# Using 3rd party API within Dialogflow Fulfillment

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've got a Dialogflow agent for which I'm using the Inline Editor (powered by Cloud Functions for Firebase). When I try to embed an HTTPS GET handler within the Intent handler, it crashes with log entry "Ignoring exception from a finished function".  Maybe there's a better way to do this with promises but I'm new to that. I can see that it does in fact execute the external query after upgrading to the Blaze plan so it's not a limitation of the billing account.  Anyhow, here's the code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//const rp = require('request-promise');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function findWidget(agent) {

    const https = require("https");
    const url = "https://api.site.com/sub?query=";

    agent.add(`Found a widget for you:`);

    var widgetName = getArgument('Name');

    https.get(url + widgetName, res => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      let body = "";
      res.on("data", data => {
        body += data;
      });
      res.on("end", () => {

        body = JSON.parse(body);

        agent.add(new Card({
            title: `Widget ` + body.name,
            text: body.description,
            buttonText: 'Open link',
            buttonUrl: body.homepage
          })
        );
      });
    });  
  }

// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
intentMap.set('Find Old Movie Intent', findOldMovie);
intentMap.set('Find Movie Intent', findMovie);
// intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

It isn't just that there is a "better" way to do it with Promises - `agent.handleRequest()` requires you to use Promises if you have any code that is being called asynchronously. The issue is that your `findWidget` function is returning before the `https.get` finishes running, so the reply doesn't end up being sent.

I tend to use the [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) package to do HTTP calls, since it simplifies many things. (However, you're free to wrap the call in a Promise yourself.) So the Promise version might look something like this (untested):

```
  var findWidget = function(agent) {

    const request = require('request-promise-native');
    const url = "https://api.site.com/sub?query=";

    agent.add(`Found a widget for you:`);

    var widgetName = getArgument('Name');

    return request.get( url+widgetName )
      .then( jsonBody => {
        var body = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
        agent.add(new Card({
          title: `Widget ` + body.name,
          text: body.description,
          buttonText: 'Open link',
          buttonUrl: body.homepage
        }));
        return Promise.resolve( agent ); 
      });
    });  
  }
```

Comment: In fact, it doesn't work with `request-promise`, gotta use the native promises.

Comment: @RichieRich can you please add how you achieved that ? and can you please add some links to where handleRequest() expects a Promise

Comment: You can use native promises with the `request-promise-native` package.

Comment: You can see the code for `handleRequest()` at https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js where it gets a response and, if that response is not a Promise, it makes it a Promise. When the promise is fulfilled, it sends what has been set. So if you're doing async operations, you need to do them in a promise.

Comment: This is a spot on answer for this question. Thanks @Prisoner.

Comment: You can edit other people's answers to fix issues like this. Fixed. Thanks for calling attention to it.