# dialogflow webhook parameters gets failed to pass

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
    const host = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/';
    const wwoApiKey = '7ffbb59524a81a6ac42ac3e942f68c5d';
    var city = req.body.queryResult.parameters['geo-city'];
    var path = 'data/2.5/weather?' +'APPID=' + wwoApiKey +'&q=' +city+'&units=imperial';
    request(host+path,function(error,response,body)
    {   
        var a=JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        var temp=a.main.temp;
        var location=a.name;
        console.log(location);
        res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': city }); 
    });


};
```

Why do I get internal server error and how can I pass values to fulfillment text via resolve function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems here, so it is difficult to know where to start.

You say you want to use dialogflow's parameters, but you haven't included the [dialogflow fulfillment library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) at all, and you're not doing any intent handling, so it isn't clear what you're having trouble with there.

When you do, you will probably want to [use Promises instead of callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49751176/1405634).

Finally, if you're getting errors, then posting the error log along with your code will help us point you in the right direction without having to run the code ourselves.

Comment: thank you..the error is because of the asynchronous request function.thank you for your help.

Comment: If this has helped, accepting and/or upvoting the answer is always appreciated.