# How to call an API from Dialog Flow using get method?

Tags: node.js, api, dialogflow-es

My question is about the the use of API in **Webhook**. I used this code for calling an external API from my localhost using ngrok. I have tried [Using 3rd party API within Dialogflow Fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744277/using-3rd-party-api-within-dialogflow-fulfillment?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well, but still not working for my case. This is my code -

```
'use strict';

var https = require ('https');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + 
JSON.stringify(request.headers));
console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function welcome(agent) {
  agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
}

function fallback(agent) {
 agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
 agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

function get_products(agent){
  var url = 'https://705861b5.ngrok.io/products';
  https.get(url, function(res){
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
      body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
     var respose_jquery = JSON.parse(body);
     agent.add("Got a response: ", respose_jquery.product_name);
    });
  }).on('error', function(e){
    agent.add("Got an error: ", e);
  });   
}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
intentMap.set('show_products', get_products);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
```

Comment: How is that request related to dialogflow?. What Dialogflow API are you trying to call?

Comment: I am building a chat-bot in Dialog flow. This is the function, I wrote in fulfilment.

Comment: You're using `inline editor` via Cloud Functions for Firebase, or the webhook?

Comment: I am using webhook

Comment: Then show your whole code, what's agent, show you'r express setup, everything.

Comment: I wrote the entire code. Thanks

Comment: what errors or output are you getting?

Comment: Default Output. "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  }

Comment: shouldn't you add 'return' before your API call (e.g. return https.get(...)) to wait for a result before resolving?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks

Comment: On doing that I get this error - "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: Are there any additional error logs? 
do add 'return' before agent.add() in your https call - so that it return something.

Comment: @imnikhilanand let us know if it fixed it

Comment: @davidverweij, The problem is still not fixed. I realised that I am using free plan. To access Non-google server one have get Blaze-Plan. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415759/use-firebase-cloud-function-to-send-post-request-to-non-google-server

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the dialogflow-fulfillment library assumes that you will return a Promise if you do any async functions, such as the https calls in your `get_products()` function.

Although you can wrap your code in something that returns a Promise, the easiest way to do this is to use something like the [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) library. It might look something like this (untested):

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

function get_products(agent){
  var url = 'https://705861b5.ngrok.io/products';
  var options = {
    uri: url,
    json: true
  };
  return rp.get( options )
    .then( body => {
      agent.add("Got a response: "+body.product_name);
    })
    .error( err => {
      agent.add("Got an error: " + e);
    });
}
```

Comment: I get error using axis, should I using request-promise-native ??  the error using axis : getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Comment: You can try, but this sounds like an unrelated problem. I suggest you [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide as many details as you can (code, what environment you're running in, etc).